# nasm x86-64 bit division

Tags: floating-point, x86-64, nasm, inline-assembly

I'm trying to divide in assembly language

I can't find a good example online on how to divide in 64 bit.

So far I have 2 values in two variabbles

```
input
input2
```

which where read in

I'm able to multiply fine, but i'm stuck on the division

so if i wan't to divide  the two integers, i'm doing

```
mov rcx, [input]

mov rdi, [input2]

idiv rcx, rdi
```

that automatically give sme an error, because the division is suppose to be only one register, so i'm assuming that when using `idiv`, it automatically divides some register, by the one you specify, so i  tried

```
idiv rcx
```

but i'm getting "floating point error"

ideas?

Comment: Your question is tagged [floating-point], but you're talking about integer division.  Which is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick look in the [documentation](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html) shows two possibilities for division involving 64-bit numbers:

> IDIV *r/m32*
>
> Signed divide EDX:EAX by *r/m32*, with result stored in EAX ← Quotient, EDX ← Remainder.
>
> IDIV *r/m64*
>
> Signed divide RDX:RAX by *r/m64*, with result stored in RAX ← Quotient, RDX ← Remainder.

It's going to be integer division though.  Your question is tagged floating point - if you want floating point division, you'll need one of the variants of the `FDIV` instruction.

Comment: ok....so do i load my integer into rdx and rax, then when i division i do idiv rax?

Comment: No, you do `idiv REGISTER_YOU_WANT_TO_DIVIDE_BY`.  Using `RDX` or `RAX` isn't going to work, since that's where your dividend is.